# Redesigning a page: changing the PHP code that generates the HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to redesign a web application and I'm getting stumped by this block of code:

```
foreach ($this->cells1 as $c) {
            $s .= $c[2] ? $c[2] : '';
            $s .= '<div style="clear:both"><table><tr><td nowrap="nowrap"' . ($c[0] ? (' ' . $c[0]) : '') . '>';
            $s .= $c[1] ? $c[1] : '&nbsp;';
            $s .= '</td>';
            $s .= $c[3] ? $c[3] : '';
        }
        $s .= '</tr></table></div>';
```

It is producing HTML code such as:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap">Search:</td>
        <form action="some-action" method="post"></form>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

 <div style="clear:both"></div>
 <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="alt-row">
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
          <input type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

 <div style="clear:both"></div>
 <table>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
       <form action="some-action" method="post"></form>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

and so on. . . .
```

and it looks like this:

[image: Disregard the size of the buttons. That's intentional]

I just want them all in a div that I can style to my taste. Can anyone please explain that section of code to me so I can work with it? 
Or better still show me an alternative way to make them fit in a div.

Comment: If I could offer any advice, it would be to move away from something like this. That code is barely readable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clarify your question to mention that you want the table structure removed.

What is happening here is the application is returning an array $this->cells1 for each item in that array it is creating a separate table using the elements it contains.

Below is a ternary if statement, what it is saying is if c[2] exists echo c[2] if not echo  '' The first thing in the line is the question then a question mark and what to do if the question is true then a colon and what to do if the question is false.

```
$c[2] ? $c[2] : '';
```

To change this to just create divs all you really need to do is remove the table mark up and replace it with whatever you need it to be.

For example:

```
foreach ($this->cells1 as $c) {
            $s .= $c[2] ? $c[2] : '';
            $s .= '<div><p>' . ($c[0] ? (' ' . $c[0]) : '');
            $s .= $c[1] ? $c[1] : '&nbsp;';
            $s .= '</p>';
            $s .= $c[3] ? $c[3] : '';
        }
        $s .= '</div>';
```

Will generate a div with the first element wrapped in a p tag.

Personally what I would do is echo out each item individually to see what it's returning, then structure the foreach accordingly because honestly it looks like it has some HTML coming back from the database too.

```
foreach($this->cells1 as $c) {

    echo 'c0:' . $c[0];
    echo 'c1:' . $c[1];
    echo 'c2:' . $c[2];
    echo 'c3:' . $c[3];
}
```

This will give you just a list of what each element is returning so you can figure out what the data looks like, after you know that figuring out what to do with it will make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div id='mycustomdiv'>";
foreach ($this->cells1 as $c) {
            $s .= $c[2] ? $c[2] : '';
            $s .= '<div style="clear:both"><table><tr><td nowrap="nowrap"' . ($c[0] ? (' ' . $c[0]) : '') . '>';
            $s .= $c[1] ? $c[1] : ' ';
            $s .= '</td>';
            $s .= $c[3] ? $c[3] : '';
        }
        $s .= '</tr></table></div>';

echo "</div>";
```

See the code above there is a echo of your custom div and echo of closing of that div. Add these echos. If you need explanation of code let me know.

Comment: I want to remove those tables totally. Any ideas?